# Select the first item in kendoComboBox

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have a form where I let users select a location using the geonames API and a kendoComboBox. However, if users select (click on) the first item in the list, this doesn't actually select the item. Only if they select any other item and then again select the first item does the selection actually work.
Selecting any other item but the first works fine.

Can anyone point me to why that might be the case and how I can fix it?
Here's my code:

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Location:</label></td>
    <td><input id="toBeSetByJS" class="locationDisplay" readonly></td>
    <td><label>Select Location:</label></td>
    <td><input class="locationSelector" id="toBeSetByJS2" type="text">{{ form.location }}</td>
</tr>

<script>              
$( ".locationSelector").each(function( index ) {

// name of hidden input element
var locationInput = $(this).next("input").attr("id");

// set names of selector and display
var locationDisplay = locationInput + "-display";
$(this).parent().prev().prev().children().attr("id", locationDisplay);                                

var locationSelector = locationInput + "-selector";
$(this).attr("id", locationSelector);       

// initialize the location display if necessary
var locationid = $("#" + locationInput).val();

if (locationid != "") {
    getLocationName(locationid, locationDisplay);
}     

var isocode = $("#isocode").val();       

$(this).kendoComboBox({
    placeholder: "Select location...",
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "geonameId",
    template: '<b>${ data.name }</b>, ${ data.adminName1 }, ${ data.countryName } (${data.fcode})',
    filter: "startswith",
    dataSource: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    countryBias: isocode,
                    username: "my.username",
                    name_startsWith: function() {
                        return $("#" + locationSelector).data("kendoComboBox").text();                          
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "geonames"   
        }
    },
    change: function() {
        $("#" + locationDisplay).val(this.text());
        $("#" + locationInput).val(this.value());

    }
});
});


function getLocationName(geoid, locationDisplayField) {

$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/getJSON",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        geonameId: geoid,
        style: "full",
        username: "my.username"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //var locName = (data.name +  ", " + data.adminName1 + ", " + data.countryName);
        $("#" + locationDisplayField).val(data.name);

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
        alert('Ooops, geonames server returned: ' + textStatus);
    }
});


}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you make [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iQuyo) to work to make this easier to help you.. ?

Answer (score 1):

To set default value of kendo combo box using JQuery, you can do like this-

```
var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.value("Europe");
```

See if this helps.

Comment: I had to use `kendoDropDownList` for my uses, but that worked, thanks!